# Getting all resolved data inside $.when

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, resolve

I am checking how to get all the resolved data inside $.when(null, promArr)

> I am getting the last resolved data inside then . But I need to get the entire resolved stuff.

```
var  _promArr = [],_prom = ''; 
        _.each(uniqueAccountList, function(obj,idx){
            _prom = getAccountDetails(obj.acctId);  
            _promArr.push(_prom); 
        });
        $.when.apply(null, _promArr).then(function(){ 

           ***I need all data passed inside resolve  here***

        }).always(function () {
            console.log('all joint promises resolved always');
        });
function getAccountDetails(accid){

  // perform ajaxcall and resolve or reject the promise

  var _def = $.Deferred();

  if (successs)
     _def.resolve({accid:accid,status:1})
  else if (fail.reason == 'Not found')  
     _def.resolve({accid:accid,status:0})
  else
     _def.reject();

  return _def
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> We can get all the resolved data inside then using **arguments**

```
$.when.apply(null, _promArr).then(function(){ 

       ***I need all data passed inside resolve  here***
var resolvedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arguments));


    }).always(function () {
        console.log('all joint promises resolved always');
    });
```